# TextView que funciona como botón dentro de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview

Tengo un RecyclerView que tiene un TextView que funciona como botón en los items, el cuál es el mismo para todos los items, lo que quiero es que al hacer click en el TextView, este me mande los datos contenidos en ese item a otra actividad y que se me agrupe en forma de lista, por ejemplo: Si un item consta del nombre y la descripcion, quiero que al hacer click en el TextView me mande el nombre y la descripcion que contiene ese item a otra actividad. El problema que tengo es, que cuando hago click en él, sí me envía el nombre y la descripcion, pero si hago click en el TextView de otro item, los campos cambian al nombre y descripcion del ultimo item seleccionado.

```
public class ListaProductosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaProductosAdapter.ProductosViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<DatosProductos> listaProductos;




    public ListaProductosAdapter(ArrayList<DatosProductos> listaProductos){
        this.listaProductos = listaProductos;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_item,null,false);
        return new ProductosViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductosViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.nombre_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getNombre_producto());
        holder.desc_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getDescripcion_producto());
        holder.precio_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getPrecio() + "€");


        holder.setOnClickListeners();


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return listaProductos.size();
    }


    public class ProductosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        //Contexto
        Context context;

        TextView nombre_producto, precio_producto,desc_producto,añadircarrito;

        public ProductosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();

            nombre_producto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mostrarNombre);
            precio_producto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mostrarPrecio);
            desc_producto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mostrarDesc);
            añadircarrito = itemView.findViewById(R.id.añadircarrito);

        }

        void setOnClickListeners(){
            añadircarrito.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Carrito.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre",nombre_producto.getText().toString());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}


'Donde quiero recibir los datos'
public class Carrito extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nom,nom1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);


        nom1 = findViewById(R.id.txtnom1);

        Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
        String dato1 = bundle1.getString("nombre");
        nom1.setText(dato1);

        nom = findViewById(R.id.txtnom);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String dato = bundle.getString("nombre");
        nom.setText(dato);

    }
}

"XML del Item"
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoproyecto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:context=".Tienda">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTienda"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                android:paddingRight="14dp"
                android:src="@drawable/poste_barbero"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/datos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgTienda"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgTienda">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mostrarNombre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mostrarDesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/añadircarrito"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:text="Añadir al carrito"
                    android:textColor="@color/carrito"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mostrarPrecio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:text="Precio"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución puede ser agregar la posición que se obtiene en `onBindViewHolder()` y agregarla como tag a una vista:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductosViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.nombre_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getNombre_producto());
        holder.desc_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getDescripcion_producto());
        holder.precio_producto.setText(listaProductos.get(position).getPrecio() + "€");
        
        //*Agrega posición como valor de la etiqueta.
        holder.nombre_producto.setTag(String.valueOf(position)); 

        holder.setOnClickListeners();


    }
```

Después se obtiene la posición y se obtiene la información del elemento.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //*Obtiene la posición.
        int posicion = Integer.parseInt(nombre_producto.getTag());
        //*Obtiene el nombre del producto.
        String nombre = listaProductos.get(posicion).getNombre_producto()

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,Carrito.class);
        intent.putExtra("nombre", nombre);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```